# AWS Target group has two instances , how does ALB selects which one to go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53, round-robin

I was wondering if a target group has two instances, how does load balancer selects between two instances ? is it randomly selected?

Answer (score 2):

This is explain in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#modify-routing-algorithm):

> By default, the **round robin routing algorithm** is used to route requests at the target group level.

You can change that, as written in the docs.